# Use .net core DLL in Framework 4.6 project

Tags: c#, .net, dll, .net-core, .net-4.6

I have built a DLL in .net core 2.0 and I now want to use it in a WinForms-project using the .net 4.6.1-framework.

I can reference the dll but I get a "System.IO.FileLoadException" which says that "System.Runtime, Version 4.2.0.0" could not be found.

What's the standard way to integrate a .net core 2.0-DLL in a full-framework-project?

Answer (score 6):

According to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) you should reference .Net Standard and to reference .Net Standard 2.0 library you should have a project on .Net Framework 4.6.1 or higher and installed .Net Core 2.0 SDK.

You should change target framework to 4.6.1 of your WinForms project and install .Net Core SDK.

Comment: I actually didn't know there was a difference between 4.6.1 and 4.6. I currently use 4.6.

Comment: @user2033412, If you change framework to 4.6.1  does it work?

Comment: @user2033412, try to reinstall System.Runtime NuGet package

Comment: @user2033412, try to unload your .Net Core project and open project file in XML editor, then find `<TargetFrameworkVersion>`. Which value do you have?

Comment: Ok, i think i got it. I changed the TragetFrameWorkVersion from dotnetcore2.0 to dotnetstandard2.0 -- now it works. :-)

Comment: To be more exact, 
`<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>` to
`<TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>`